# unity3d loading spritesheet from web and memory issue

Tags: unity-game-engine, memory, sprite-sheet, atlas

I am making an interactive book application that player will curl pages and will see spritesheet animations per page. I have tried to load sprites seperately(300 images with 512x512 size). But when i tried this method, ipad crashes and saying about memory issue. I have checked memory profile on unity and the application was loading '1.2 GB' into ram. It's so huge so ipad is right.

So first thing i think that I need to load only specify number of pages and when player turns pages to forward, I may load new assets and destroy previous page assets. When I tried it, when player turns the page, its freezing some seconds to load new sprites and its too bad for user experience.

Second thing I am thinking right now, let's say i have 30 frames for 1 sprite animation, just putting 30 frames into a texture and use only this texture for sprite animation. I mean that instead of using 30 different images, I need to use 1 sprite atlas texture which contains all frames, and I can change rect in runtime to present sprite animation. But I don't know how can I use only 1 texture to present 30 frames?

Answer (score 0):

> When I tried it, when player turns the page, its freezing some seconds to load new sprites and its too bad for user experience

Assuming this is a linear setup, you can just store plus or minus 5 pages at a time. If I'm on page 1, load page 2-6, when I turn the page, load page 7. when I get to page 6, remove page 1. There will be a trade off of performance vs memory allocation, so you will have to make the call of how many pages to cache.

> But I don't know how can I use only 1 texture to present 30 frames?

I'm not sure how you have your sprite texture set up, but you can make a sprite into multiple sprites by setting the `spriteImportMode` to `SpriteImportMode.Multiple`. You can then define the bounds of each sprite via the parent sprites `spriteMetaData`. You can also change this in the unity editor, but from what you are describing, you will have to do it programatically.

I'm fairly certain that this is *not* the ideal path to go down. You may want to look into Unity Tilemaps to come up with a more robust answer.

Comment: How are you handling the load? Can you provide some code examples?